# Could some one guide me how to integrate JMeter Jenkins Report JIRA

Tags: jmeter

Now as soon as JMeter test finishes from Jenkins  I have configured email attachment.

In the same way, I want to send the report to JIRA. How can I do that?

Could some one guide me please?

Thanks,
Raj

Answer (score 0):

JIRA has REST API so you should be able to create a issue of your choice in a single HTTP Request just like you send email with the results.

Useful links:

- [JIRA REST API Reference](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/)
- [JIRA REST API Example - Create Issue](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/jira-rest-api-example-create-issue)
- [Testing SOAP/REST Web Services Using JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/testing-soaprest-web-services-using-jmeter)

Comment: Hi Dmitri, The links are informative for web services testing and REST API testing, but I am looking  how to integrate JMeter report for the tests executed from CI-Rajani